# PVMFFailure on MediaPlayer init on moment, but not on Nexus one

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

I have a VideoView that is playing back some .mp4 files from sdcard.  The code works fine on a Nexus one (2.3), Samsung Galaxy (both TMobile and AT&T versions on 2.2), even a Viewsonic tablet, but when I try it on a Samsung Moment on 2.1, I get a pop-up saying "Sorry, this video can not be played", and the logcat has some rather terse messages (below), which mostly pull up issues with streaming or MP3 files.  The video is H.264/AAC - does it need to be H.264/MP3?

Logcat:

> W/MediaPlayer( 2538): info/warning (1, 26)
>       I/MediaPlayer( 2538): Info (1,26)
>       E/PlayerDriver( 1891): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
>       E/MediaPlayer( 2538): error (1, -1)
>       E/MediaPlayer( 2538): Error (1,-1)
>       D/VideoView( 2538): Error: 1,-1
>       W/PlayerDriver( 1891): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a couple things.  I contacted Samsung support, and got a very stock reply with the list of codecs and sizes supported.  Sizes?  That's right, the Moment does not support any 16:9 format video sizes.  I changed it to 4:3, but it still didn't play using an mp4 container (even though it should have, using H.264).  So I changed to a 3gp container with H.264, and it worked.  Here was the list from Samsung:

Thank you for your correspondence.

These are the video formats and specification supported by the Samsung Moment (SPH-M900):

Codecs: 
MPEG-4 SP 
MPEG-4 AVC 
H.263

File Formats: 
3GP/3G2 
MP4 
AVI 
WMV

Video Pixel Resolution: 
640 X 480 
352 X 288 
320 X 240 
176 X 144

Frames Per Second: 
15, 30

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Following this link may help.

[getting PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback error while playing mp4 files on samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874191/getting-pvmferrcontentinvalidforprogressiveplayback-error-while-playing-mp4-files/6898074#6898074)

Also you may find a little help for using Mp4Box with GUI throught this link

[Android MP4 moov mdat problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952330/android-mp4-moov-mdat-problem/6980289#6980289)

Comment: This one seems to be more relating to streaming video to the videoview, and what isn't playing on the moment is playing on a Galaxy.