# Android MP4 moov mdat problem

Tags: android, video, mp4

I am developing app where I have to play progressive steaming video of mp4 file. But I faced the `PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback` error. I think that those videos are not satisfing any of those requirements - "For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the `moov` atom must precede any `mdat` atoms." How can I convert those file which will satsfy that format? Is there any converter for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GUI version, Under options menu i selected "hint for rtp/rtsp". 
Then in Mux tab, I added mp4 file with add button. After that pressed Mux button in the right bottom corner.

It creates the muxed version in the same directory path of your mp4 file. You can use save as for different location.

The newly created file worked for me and didnt give PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback error.

Answer (score 2):

Use [MP4Box](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box) with the `-hint` switch to fix this issue.

Comment: i have downloaded GUI version of MP4box. I have tried with different -hint option. But still it is giving PVMFErrResourceConfiguration error. can you tell which specific option I have to select?

Comment: @dalandroid: sorry, I have only used the command-line version. Also, since your error changed, I think you solved the `moov`/`mdat` problem but have some other issue.

Comment: For what this PVMFErrResourceConfiguration problem may arise? any idea? I have tested with some other test 3gp progressive steaming video, they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the -hint just add interleaving at the end of the file (which is not enough).

You may use a program called Handbrake ([here](http://handbrake.fr/)), where you can select "Web Optimize" option 
to switch/re-arrange *moov* and *mdat* atoms places for progressive download.

The idea is to switch places between the MP4 container headers and the actual movie data, so you may start streaming immediately

You can further read about the solution here: [How to correctly encode .mp4 files for streaming](http://blog.rachaelbond.com/encode-mp4/)